# How to get up to last record from Generate series from 00 - 23:59 time but with 15 minutes interval

Tags: postgresql, generate-series

I am trying to use generate_series in postgres so that I can get all the last record from 00:00 - 23:59 with 15 minutes interval, the problem is, I only receive 23:45 for the last record, how does it work with 00:00 - 23:59 so that I can get the last record which is 23:59

Note that time here is actually from the column but I put the value here directly.

Here is the query,

```
generate_series(('00:00:00' + '2021-10-03'::date)::timestamp,('23:59:00' + '2021-10-03'::date )::timestamp, interval '15m') as "time"
```

Comment: Unrelated, but: `('00:00:00' + '2021-10-03'::date)::timestamp`  can be simplified to  `'2021-10-03 00:00:00'::timestamp`

Comment: 23:59 is not a 15min interval. So, obviously you cannot receive a record like this when you generate only 15min steps. The only way I see is to generate your series and then add the 23:59 record with a UNION clause. But then you'll get a 14min step - I am not quite sure if this is really intended.

Answer (score 1):

Can we do it like this:

```
SELECT generate_series('2021-10-03 00:00'::timestamp,'2021-10-03 23:59', '15 minute')
union 
SELECT generate_series('2021-10-03 23:59'::timestamp,'2021-10-03 23:59', '1 minute');
```

Or

```
SELECT generate_series('2021-10-03 00:00'::timestamp,'2021-10-03 23:59', '15 minute')
union 
SELECT '2021-10-03 23:59';
```

Not sure if it is correct way or not.

Comment: The second version is better.

Comment: how can I add one more data without using union ? is there other way around ?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating a single value for each create a time zone range ([tsrange](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/rangetypes.html#RANGETYPES-BUILTIN)). In creating the range indicate it is to include the lower bound but not the upper bound.

```
select tsrange( ts, ts+interval '15 min', '[)') timestamp_range
  from generate_series('2021-10-03 00:00'::timestamp  -- ts 1
                      ,'2021-10-03 23:59'::timestamp  -- ts 2 
                      ,'15 minute'
                      )  gn(ts);
```

The ranges can be extended as you want just by changing the `ts 1` and/or `ts 2`.